# jQuery toggle background color on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have a two radio controls that are designed as buttons. When I click the first radio button, then second one's background color should change and vice versa.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="boo1" name="boo" value="boo1"><label for="boo1"><span></span>boo1</label>
<input type="radio" id="boo2" name="boo" value="boo2"><label for="boo2"><span></span>boo2</label>
```

CSS:

```js
body {
font-family: open sans, arial, sans-serif;
color: #ffffff;
margin: 0;
background: #3894db;
}
input[type="radio"] {
display: none;
}
input[type="radio"] + label {
cursor: pointer;
width: 50%;
height: auto;
font-size: 22px;
margin-top: 10px;
float: left;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-top: 2px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
}
/* boo1 */
#boo1 + label {
background: #e74c3c;
}
#boo1:checked + label {
background: #c0392b;
}
/* boo2 */
#boo2 + label {
background: #f1c40f;
}
#boo2:checked + label {
background: #f39c12;
}
```

JavaScript?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#boo1").click(function () {

});
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What color should the background of each button be?

Comment: it states the colors of each background in the style example i gave. i don't care what the colors are because i can change that. i just need a code that would change the color of the other radio button when one is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the buttons to have different background colors when "inactive", you can use jQuery's [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#boo1").click(function () {
        $("#boo1 + label").css("background-color", "#c0392b");
        $("#boo2 + label").css("background-color", "green");
    });
    $("#boo2").click(function () {
        $("#boo2 + label").css("background-color", "#f39c12");
        $("#boo1 + label").css("background-color", "blue");
    });
});
```

See [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Filly/aR6x3/).

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('#boo1').is(':checked'))
{
     $('#boo2').css('color','#ff0000');
}
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work. I thought it would, i tried it, except of using 'color

Comment: I have updated the answer, please try it through jQuery; and make sure the control reaches this snippet when the radio-button is checked.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
$("#boo1").click(function (event) {

                $("#boo2").prop( "checked",true );
            });

            $("#boo2").click(function (event) {

                $("#boo1").prop( "checked",true );
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='boo']").click(function () {
        $(this).next().removeAttr('style');
        $("input[name='boo']").not(this).next().css('background-color', 'green');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

**HTML CODE:**

```
      <label for="boo1"><span><input type="radio" id="boo1" name="boo" value="boo1" /></span>boo1</label>
      <label for="boo2"><span><input type="radio" id="boo2" name="boo" value="boo2" /></span>boo2</label>
```

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
        $('input[type=radio]').on('click', function () {
             $('input[type=radio]').not(this).closest('label').css('background', 'blue');
             $(this).closest('label').css('background', 'red');
        });
```

**LIVE DEMO:**

Happy Coding :)
http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/py2BM/14/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with pure CSS

```
/* boo1 */
#boo1 + label {
background: #e74c3c;
}
#boo1:checked ~ label[for="boo2"] {
background: #c0392b;
}
#boo1:checked ~ label[for="boo1"]{
    background: #f39c12;
}
/* boo2 */
#boo2 + label {
background: #f1c40f;
}
#boo2:checked ~ label[for="boo1"] {
background: #f39c12;
}
```

working demo:http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/S6z8Z/

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and optimized solution:**

**HTML Code:**

```
<!-- Fieldset Wrap: begins -->
<div class="fieldset-wrap">

    <!-- Fieldset: begins -->
    <span class="fieldset orange">
        Label 1
    </span>
    <!-- Fieldset: ends -->

    <!-- Fieldset: begins -->
    <span class="fieldset green">
       Label 2
    </span>
    <!-- Fieldset: ends --> 

</div>
<!-- Fieldset Wrap: ends -->
```

**CSS:**

```
.fieldset-wrap {
    overflow: hidden; 
    font-size:0px;
}

.fieldset { 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 14px;
 }

.fieldset { margin-left: 1px; }
.fieldset:first-child { margin-left: 0px; }

.orange,
.green,
.checked{ color: #fff; }

.orange { background-color : orange; }
.green { background-color : green; }
.checked { background-color : blue; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.fieldset').on('click', function(){
    $(this)  
    .addClass('checked')
    .siblings()
    .removeClass('checked');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ipLAq)